# Using 'ruby' with no arguments freezes terminal

Tags: ruby

I'm a Ruby newbie and have Ruby 1.9.3 installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Whenever I run the `ruby` command in the terminal with no arguments, it just hangs and does nothing. It does the same thing on my Windows XP installation.

Is this the expected behavior? Coming from a Python/Java background I expected some kind of output.

Comment: Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on this very day is a shame. Ruby 2.0 was just released.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 will be very viable for a while. v2.0, while it's the latest and greatest, is also an unknown in some ways, and will be revealing some bugs over the next couple weeks. There's "bleeding edge" and there's stability. Beginners should get used to 1.9+ as the vast majority of documentation will apply to it, the gems work fine, and let v2.0 get its wrinkles ironed out.

Comment: @sawa just know that!!! So quiet release..

Comment: Really @theTinMan Ruby newbie? Then I don't even know how to programming...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Nobody was calling you a newbie. The OP says "I'm a Ruby newbie", and the comment was directed there in reference to @sawa's comment.

Comment: @theTinMan I think texabruce is somehow by mistake taking it that you are called newbie, and compared to that, texabruce would be even more newbie, considering your skills. I don't know why texabruce mistook it, as well as why you mistook it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected. When you run just `ruby`, it sits there, waiting for a program from STDIN, followed by an end-of-file character, after which it executes the program.

If you want interactive, like when you run `python`, you want Ruby's `irb`.

Answer (score -2):

- to check your ideas in console

  type `irb`
- to run a program in console

  type `ruby program_I_want_to_run.rb`