# Can't start ruby from osx yosemite terminal, before and after rbenv, homebrew works though

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, osx-yosemite, rbenv

Every time I type `ruby` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at my terminal, it just hangs for seemingly forever. This is happening for the default Yosemite install and after I installed with rbenv, using Homebrew (which works fine), using "[Ruby on Rails development setup for Mac OSX](http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/)".

My current Ruby version is 2.2.2, `ruby -v` works, and I didn't have this problem when I was using OS X Mavericks.

Has anyone else had this problem and/or found a solution? My google-fu doesn't seem to be strong enough.

Comment: Don't use instructions on other sites to install things like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install). Instead use the instructions provided by the maintainers of those tools as they know how it works and how best to use that particular tool. Homebrew is great for installing libraries not installed on Mac OS, but use rbenv or RVM to install and manage Ruby. Doing otherwise makes it more complicated than it needs to be, and with complication comes confusion.

Comment: This already seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053495/5175676.

Comment: @theTinMan fair enough, but I feel my issue is an issue with the ruby runtime in general, as I've had this problem since I installed os x yosemite on my machine. From what I can tell, the link I posted above follows pretty closely with rbenvs official tutorial. I also tried installing with RVM a while back, following RVM's official tutorial. Still, ruby hangs when I try to start it

Comment: @Sri oh... thanks. This is awkward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter `ruby` at the command-line, it's supposed to "hang forever". It's waiting for you to give it instructions. You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get it to stop waiting:

```
> ruby
puts 1 + 1
2
```

I then did <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and returned to the command-line prompt.

Instead though, we don't use Ruby like that. If we want to use it interactively, we use IRb which comes with Ruby. It's the "interactive" Ruby:

```
> irb
Welcome to IRB. You are using ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin13]. Have fun ;)
>> 1 + 1
2
>> 'foo'.squeeze('o')
"fo"
```

If we want to run a Ruby script, we use something like:

```
ruby /path/to/script
```

and Ruby will load and run it.

I'd recommend reading some Ruby tutorials and learn how the language works before trying to use Rails. Rails uses deep Ruby magic and how Rails works will be unfathomable to you until you do understand better how Ruby is used and how it works and what it can do.

If you're using rbenv to manage your Ruby, then when you enter `rbenv versions` you should see the Rubies it manages listed:

```
rbenv versions
  system
  1.9.3-p551
* 2.2.2 (set by /Users/tinman/.rbenv/version)
```

If you don't, either rbenv isn't in control of Ruby, or you haven't installed any using rbenv. `rbenv global system` will tell it to use whatever you have installed by default in the system, based on your PATH.

rbenv's documentation and built-in help go over this so if the problems continue then you need to closely examine your install and setup, because 90% of the problems we see using a sandboxed Ruby are due to people not paying attention to the directions, or using the wrong ones, and not completing the installation.

Comment: thanks, someone else posted the same thing.  I guess I thought it would be like python with a standard repl (guess i shouldnt make these kind of assumptions about scripting languages)

Comment: Ruby *does* ship with a standard REPL, called IRb, which has its own script called `irb`. Also, different Ruby implementations behave differently. For example, Rubinius, when called without any arguments, *will* start IRb, similarly to how CPython does it.